# How to attach stylesheet to HTML email?

Tags: html, css, email

I want to include `normalize.css` in a HTML email. However various tutorials advise that all css should be inline, as some email clients ignore linked styles in the head. In such case how can I include `normalize.css`?

The only reason I want to use `normalize.css` is so that it takes out the padding around the edge of the browser.

Comment: And why exactly do you want to include whole normalize.css if all you need is to remove the padding???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only reason I want to use normalize is so that it takes out the padding around the edge of the browser.

That's just:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Go read the source code for Normalize, line 19:

https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css

You can just inline that one bit, where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Put your css in `<style>` tags.

```
<style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        ...etc;
    }
</style>
```